# Angular - emitted function event doesn't get through to parent component

Tags: javascript, angular

Here is the child component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'detail-component',
  templateUrl: './detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detail.component.css'],
})
export class DetailComponent extends AbstractFormComponent{
  constructor() { }

  @Output()
  settingEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();

  onPageChangeEvent(settings: any) {
         this.settingEvent.emit(4);
  }

}
```

And part of the template that concerns the emitter

```
<parent-component (settingEvent)="setting($event)"></parent-components>
```

Here is the parent component

```
setting(event: any){
   console.log('test')
}
```

its not inside the setting function. Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: I see settingEvent  is available in app-detail component not in detail-operations

Comment: are you getting any error in the console?
your component's selector is `app-detail`, but you are using `detail-operations` in the template.

Comment: So If you want to get value from settingEvent you must call to app-detail  instead of detail-operations

Comment: if you have installed [Angular Language Service extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template), try to CTRL+ LEFT CLICK on the `(settingEvent)` in your template. If your clicking not responding, meaning something is wrong.

Comment: I have updated my code above

Comment: you  have test string in your console or not?

Comment: whatever you put in the `selector` of `child component`, use the **same** in the parent component's template. use `<detail-component...` not `<parent-component...`

Comment: Have you tried putting a console.log inside of onPageChangeEvent to check if this function is called?

Comment: Last time I had this happen, there was a mistake in my HTML markup.  Check that thoroughly